# SOQL Combine queries to fetch Contacts with their ContactRelationRoles

Tags: apex, soql, lightning-web-components

I have these two queries, to fetch Contact info:

```
SELECT  Id, FirstName, LastName, Email FROM Contact 
  WHERE Id IN (SELECT ContactId FROM AccountContactRelation 
                WHERE AccountId = '0012o00002RGvUCAA1' AND isDirect=false)
```

And to fetch related to that Contact ContactRole from **AccountContactRelation**

```
SELECT Roles FROM AccountContactRelation 
  WHERE ContactId ='0032o00002Rp1E9AAJ' AND  AccountId = '0012o00002RGvUCAA1'
```

Is there a way to combine these two into one query, to have a collection of objects with full contact data including roles? Or if not, how can I combine their results so that it'd be possible to use them from my LWC?